# Why is sprintf ignoring padding modifiers?

Tags: c, arduino, cortex-m

I have an Apollo3 board (ARM Cortex M4). I have some code that prints memory:

I run the following code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  char lineBuffer[50];
  sprintf(lineBuffer, "%2d %04d %04x", 2, 3422, 3422);
  Serial.println(lineBuffer);
}
```

The output is `2 3422 d5e`

My question is, why not what I expect:  `2 3422 0d5e`? Why is the padding being ignored? I'm aware of issues with `%f`, are there other such problems to be wary of?

What version of the standard library is being used by Arduino here?

Comment: Just to rule out potential UB: what is the size of `lineBuffer`?

Comment: Please format the actual output as code. Also please try to create a [mre] to show us, the problem might lie elsewhere.

Comment: sizeof(lineBuffer) is 50

Comment: Creating a minimal reproducible example on Arduino is not easy--there's no stdout! But will see what I can do.

Comment: Are you sending the output over a serial line? What happens on the receiving end in that case? Have you checked that the serial data is transmitted correctly using some other terminal program? And doesn't the Arduino IDE come with a debugger?

Comment: Is the first `0` missing? Your uart may be broken and misses first character. Could you output the message each loop and confirm it's not connection.

Comment: The output is exactly as shown. I can display this on a screen, over serial, in a loop, etc. I do not have a debugger, because it does not make sense for my board, and because I am using IDE 1.8 which doesn't include one.

Comment: So what happens with `sprintf(lineBuffer, "%02d %04d %04x", 1, 2, 3);`? What is the output of `sprintf(lineBuffer, "%s", _NEWLIB_VERSION)` after `#include <_newlib_version.h>`?

Comment: @KamilCuk The output of your last snippet is `1 2 3`. _NEWLIB_VERSION is `3.0.0`.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://forums.mbed.com/t/sprintf-with-03x-does-not-left-pad-with-0/8915/13

Comment: It would be great if you could find and post the content of `include/newlib.h` file in your compiler path. We could try `#include <newlib.h>` and then `#if _WANT_IO_C99_FORMATS Serial.println("_WANT_IO_C99_FORMATS"); #endif`, but would  be nice to see all options. It could be potentially that arduino has its own sprintf implementation.

Comment: did you try `"%02d %04d %04x` instead of `"%2d %04d %04x`?

Answer (score 0):

Arduino just does this. I  believe the library mbed uses is [here](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/platform/source/minimal-printf/README.md#usage). Its docs say:

> Width size and prepending zero modifiers are supported. All other flags are ignored.

I worked around this problem by instead importing [LibPrntf](https://github.com/embeddedartistry/arduino-printf) by Embedded Artistry, which is available in the list of libraries built in to the Arduino IDE.

The new program is:

```
#include <LibPrintf.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  char lineBuffer[50];
  sprintf_(lineBuffer, "%2d %04d %04x", 2, 3422, 3422);
  Serial.println(lineBuffer);
}
```

Comment: This seems inconsistent with the documentation you quote, which claims that width size is supported.

Comment: That's a good point. Maybe you should provide a better answer, which I'd be happy to accept!